# BaseTextField issue in onKeyEvent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

This is my code for BasicTextField

```
BasicTextField(
    modifier = Modifier.onKeyEvent {
        if (it.key == Key.Backspace) {
            Timber.tag("KEY PRESSED").i(" BACKSPACE")
            onBackSpace.invoke()
            return@onKeyEvent true
        }

        return@onKeyEvent true
    },
    value = pinText,
    onValueChange = {
        if (it.isDigitsOnly())
            onPinTextChange.invoke(it)
    },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
    singleLine = true,
    maxLines = 1,
```

}

Now when I press backspace it works just fine, but when I enter a text, and then press backspace, it sometimes call onValueChange also after calling onBackSpace event inside onKeyEvent. But this only happens when I input some text. If the textfield is already populated, it works just fine.